# What is the meaning of 'controlAggregation' in the SAPUI5 routing configuration?

Tags: sapui5

I really don't get what the property controlAggregation below does for routing a SAPUI5 application.
There is not element with that id. I cant find any reference to 'pages' anywhere in the demo app found here:  [SAPUI5 routing demo](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/d9efab307ecc42b180b12cc8956e22d7.html)

```
"routing": {
        "config": {
            "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
            "viewType": "XML",
            "viewPath": "sap.ui.demo.nav.view",
            "controlId": "app",
            "controlAggregation": "pages",   // what does this do?
            "transition": "slide",
            "bypassed": {
                "target": "notFound"
            }
```

The views are defined as below- no mention of 'pages'

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="sap.ui.demo.nav.controller.App"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    displayBlock="true">
    <App id="app"/>
</mvc:View>
```

And

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="sap.ui.demo.nav.controller.Home"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
    <Page title="{i18n>homePageTitle}" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
        <content>
            <Button id="displayNotFoundBtn" text="{i18n>DisplayNotFound}" press="onDisplayNotFound" class="sapUiTinyMarginEnd"/>
        </content>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

Comment: where you want to put the view?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

controlAggregation is the target aggregation to which the view is added.

like in this case target is an sap.m.App whose id is **app**.

app has an aggregation named as **pages**.

For detail see [routing configuration](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/902313063d6f45aeaa3388cc4c13c34e.html).

> UPDATED IN DETAIL:

Assume controlId is the your container for pages and the *container's content* is going to be changed for each different routes.

Here *container's content* is nothing but the pages aggregation of app.

While we use routing, you just need a configuration of the routes and there targets. Let's take one example
[image]

So when you navigateTo `category/{id}`, sapui5 finds out what is the *target* for that pattern in the routes. Here it is `category`.

Next it finds the `viewName` for this target(Here it is category) inside the `targets` object(see after routes array there is a targets object containing  catagory,products...). 
So SapUI5 got the view to render. But where to render this view?

The answer is - it will find the controlAggregation (inside category) mentioned for that viewName. In this example, it is there called `masterPages`. now it will find what is the `controlId` in the `config`. It is `splitApp`. So Finally it got to know all the required information. i.e:

1. `viewName : Category` ,
2. `controlId(the container of view) : splitApp`
3. `controlAggregation : masterPage`

Now sapui5 will render `Category` view inside the `masterPage` aggregation of `splitApp`.

But Note ----** In your case if controlAggegation is not mentioned in the `targets` object, It is mentioned in the `config`. That means for all the views there is a common controlAggregation that is pages.

So In this case sapui5 will render your views inside the `pages` aggregation of `app`.

I think you understand the flow now.

Comment: Also, take a look at the `<pages>` in the example: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.core.tutorial.navigation.01/code/webapp%252Fview%252FApp.view.xml

Comment: yes I see that in your example - but i dont see pages in the demo called ' Navigation - Step 5 - Display a Target Without Changing the Hash'

Comment: does the sap ui5 library add this aggregation by default?

Comment: Yes. if you instatanciate a sapui5 control, it automatically creations its aggregations, by default these aggregations will be blank. you need to add it by yourself. like: app.addPage(somePage), layout.addContent(someContent).. So an aggregation indicates inner elements of an element

Comment: I think my confusion is caused by where these controlaggregations are created - I think they are created by ui5 - and in the config we just refer to them; as opposed to a div /element/object that the developer creates. To verify please answer this - can  i decide that i want the controllaggregation to be called 'homepages'?

Comment: no you cannot. you can decide the controlId(here it is app). but you have to use whatever aggregations that control provides. app provides an aggregation called pages. If you want to use app as an container then you have to use pages as controlAggregation. Think in different way, If you were use a verticalLayout as container instead of app. You need to use "content" as controlAggregation.

Comment: Can you please explain what aggregation means, before you build the whole answer on it? I hear this term for the first time in the context of a mvc framework. Thanks.

Comment: @Denis "Aggregation" describes the parent and child relationship: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44341132/5846045