# Aggregation in SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

Can anybody explain what exactly Aggregation means in SAP UI5 ? 
I am trying to make an app with two views and i want to navigate from one view to another and vice -versa. 
So , the APP control is having aggregation , so i am confused what Aggregation is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic definition of «aggregation» from [Glossary](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/9ef211e569ed4f819af904ba360ea7f6.html):

> An aggregation (in the context of UI5) is a special relation between two UI element types. It is used to define the **parent-child relationship** [...]. The parent end of the aggregation has [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_(data_modeling)) *0..1*, while the child end may have *0..1* or *0..**.

For example, a [list](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#constructor) may have 0 or many items. An item has 0 or 1 list **as its parent**. Therefore, the list has an *aggregation* of «items».

---

In our case, the control `sap.m.App`, which is extended from [`sap.m.NavContainer`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.NavContainer.html), has a default aggregation named «pages» where we can define a collection of anything extended from `sap.ui.core.Control` as its child controls.

> pages: sap.ui.core.Control **[ ]**

But just adding the views manually into `<pages></pages>` is an anti-pattern since a view has usually a [Page](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Page.html) in it and a single page takes up 100% of the height which pushes other views away. Besides that, it makes implementing navigation much more difficult.

Instead, the current best practice is to use a so-called «[router](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.routing.Router.html)» which is usually defined in the application descriptor (manifest.json) with other navigation properties. Its sister control [Target takes care](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.46/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/routing/async/Target.js#L57) of adding the navigated view to the «pages» aggregation. To find out how to achieve navigation using a router, take a look at these resources:

- Examples: [Basic navigation](https://embed.plnkr.co/wp6yes/), [navigation inside a static parent control](https://embed.plnkr.co/HRSJ44/)
- «[Routing and Navigation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/e5200ee755f344c8aef8efcbab3308fb.html)» from *Walkthrough* (see also further steps)
- «[Routing and Navigation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/3d18f20bd2294228acb6910d8e8a5fb5.html)» from *Essentials* to understand the basic concepts.

Answer (score 4):

This question is a little too broad for SO and you did not really investigate before by e.g. reading the documentation. Hence the downvotes.

Nevertheless, I will link you to the appropriate [documentation page](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f0a22d6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) and provide a short excerpt and explication:

> Controls can aggregate other controls. These controls with aggregations serve as a container or layout control to which the application can add child controls. They can also serve as composite controls if the control itself adds child controls and reuses available components. In an aggregation, child controls are owned by the parent control and are destroyed together with the parent control. A control can only have one aggregation parent. Adding the control to another aggregation removes it from the previous parent control.

In a nutshell, aggregations in UI5 have mostly the same meaning as a typical [OOP aggregation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/oop-concepts/composition-and-aggregation.html): they represent `has-a` or conversely a `is-a-part-of` relationship between controls. Tables have rows, rows have cells and so on. The lifecycles of the related controls are bound (when the parent is destroyed, the children are also destroyed).

When looking strictly at aggregations, a UI5 application consists of a tree of controls, where the controls of one level are part of an aggregation of a control from the level above.

Each aggregation has its own semantics. For example the `items` of a `sa.m.Table` are displayed between the `header` and the `footer` and the `pages` of a `NavContainer` are displayed one at a time. The behavior of the aggregation contents is generally described in the SDK reference.

Comment: "In an aggregation, child controls are owned by the parent control and are destroyed together with the parent control." ... I think UI5 is mixing the concept of *composition* up with *aggregation*. Both resources, the one you [mentioned](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/oop-concepts/composition-and-aggregation.html#Aggregation) as well as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation), say the opposite: "Aggregation (...) does not imply ownership.". UI5 should've used the term *composition* rather than *aggregation*. What do you think?

Comment: I think it is a little more complicated, but it is really up to the semantics you are using. In my view, in a composition relationship the child cannot exist without a parent. In UI5, you can actually remove one Button from a Toolbar's content aggregation and place it somewhere else. Also, a Button may exist by itself and has its own identity, regardless of its parent. On the other hand, when a parent control is destroyed, so are its children, so their lifecycles are bound. IMO in UI5 the concept of "aggregation" is actually a mixture between classical "aggregation" and "composition".

Comment: Good insights. :) Especially the last sentence. Being such a huge framework, I guess it's not easy to find a right word that fits to the concept precisely.